# Mobile devices offline sync with webservice

Tags: android, web-services, synchronization

Im am developing a webservice for an App that I am writing. I want to make the App offline accessible.

I made that webservice so that if you request JSON from the webservice you can give a date:
/color/colors/date/2014-03-01T12:00/

If you don't give the date you will get everything that is inside the database and that is active. If you give the date you will only get everything that is updated after that date.

Now my problem is that if I remove something from the webservice of from the App then it will not be synced and the other devices will never know that it is removed.

I could work with a field where I say that a record is removed but then I need to keep every record and I can't delete any record.

**Is there a better way to do the syncing? Or what is the best way?**

Comment: TL'DR: you sync current state of your data. Not changes since date.

Comment: @Budius No I am trying to sync only the data that is changed after the last update. But I have a problem with deleting data in my current system.

Comment: As I am helping Ghost in developing this app, here's some insight.
The web service pushes data to mobile phones. The phone app isn't all that big on information and most of the data gets collected asynchronous. We think the best option would be to delete and refresh the all tables if an update occurs. No table will exceed 200 records. Another questions would be: If we have 10 tables containing 200 records, would this process slow down the app to that point that it's performance is too slow?

Comment: @RobbieVercammen yea that is true :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no possible way to detect the deleted entry's change, unless you send the information that the entry is deleted. The best practise you set a field in the table with integer type, then you can set this value on updates. You don't have to set it only 1 or 0, you can use bigger numbers (for example I used 30 on that entries, that I deleted on 20th march , on this day was a big code logic change. after that i knew when the status integer is 30, then i deleted this row after that date.) It may be a silly example, but you can implement your own logic.

Comment: So if you delete a row you put a column on value 30. Then all the platforms connected to the webservice knows that 30 means delete.

But if you put the value on 30 the row will never be removed? Will it excist forever in the database. Is this ok?

Comment: i understand that, but you will know 30 was a delete 3 months ago, i can delete all the rows, where delete flag is 30.

Comment: So you cache everything 3 months? and then delete it. And if an app doens't have updated in 3 months then it is a now active user?

Comment: 3 months was just an example..you can cache it for years. how much data will be stored in the database? 1-200 won't occour any performance issue

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how important it is to update the rest of the devices when a change is made.

If it is critical, then it would be worth implementing push notifications or something similar to each device to let them know about the updated situation. Otherwise, you would simply have the other devices poll the server to check for changes on their own accord, and the frequency or the trigger of this poll would depend again on how critical it was that they get an update. Maybes they only need updating when they visit a certain activity, so in that case you would only poll when you reach the onResume() event of that activity

**Update**

If you don't need to keep a history of the deleted record, then why can't you just delete it, and then when the rest of the devices update, you clear all and download a fresh set? If that is too intensive, you would NEED to have a reference to the id, which you could do in a table or use a special value in the field (like null, 0 or -1) to mark it. Otherwise there would be no way to reference it

Comment: I know when to sync that is not the problem, the problem is when I delete a record.

Comment: Ah, so the issue is actually on the server side. I updated my answer

Comment: A table with deleted values is an interesting choise :)